# Difference between the two recursive option of grep

Tags: unix, grep

Is there any difference between the two options '-R' and '-r' of grep or is that only for universalise this option ?

Comment: `man grep`. Read. The answer is no. They are same. But you read futher then you realize that `-RS` will also follow sym-links recursively, where as `-rS` will not.

Comment: for GNU grep, `The -R options follows all symbolic links, unlike -r which follows symbolic links only if they are on the command line`

Comment: This question is about general usage of a unix command, not about programming. It is probably a better fit for http://SuperUser.com/.

Answer (score 4):

> ***-r***
>
> ***--recursive***
>
> For each directory operand, read and process all files in that
> directory, recursively. Follow symbolic links on the command
> line, **but skip symlinks that are encountered recursively**. Note that if
> no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory. This is
> the same as the ‘--directories=recurse’ option.
>
> ---
>
> **-R**
>
> ***--dereference-recursive***
>
> For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, recursively, **following all symbolic
> links.**

The difference is that `-R` option lets *following all symbolic links*.
https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: only if `-S` is also specified. Otherwise both `-r` and `-R` are are same.